# jQuery detect submit on form problem

Tags: forms, ajax, javascript

I'm trying to detect when a form is submitted so I have written this code:

```
jQuery('#formid').submit(function(event){
        console.log('submit handler');
})
```

But nothing happens and the form is submitted normally. The form is rendered as usual and the submit button is generated with this code:

```
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Enviar'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('btn','pull-right')),
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'contact_form_ajax_submit',
        'wrapper' => $result_wrapper,
        'progress' => array(
          'type' => 'none',
          'message' => NULL,
        ),
    ),
  );
```

I don't know why my jquery script doesn't intercept the submit. I've checked the form id (obviously) so I ask for help because I have no idea about what could be the problem.

Thanks

Link: http://seminolaproducciones.com/contacto

Comment: I believe you need to `return false;` after the `console.log` to stop the form from submitting.

Comment: Tried this: jQuery('#contact-result-wrapper').submit(function(event){
        console.log('submit handler'); return false;
}) with the same result

Comment: Check [this API page](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) especially the 2nd example.

Comment: Only reason why returning false won't work is the function is never run in the first place.

Comment: I know but I don't understand why I can't detect the submit on my form. I'm going to update my answer with a link to my page so you see the form and the problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: It's probably because you're using #ajax on the submit button as well so your callback is overridden. You may be able to add the js submit handler as part of a Drupal.behaviors function instead. Note, you can validate the form server side with ajax if you want.

Answer (score 2):

For normal forms you need bind submit event handler to the form, something like below as Baysaa said,

```
jQuery('#formid').submit(function() {
  console.log('submit handler');
  return false;
});
```

However For Drupal AJAX forms this wont work, Because Drupal AJAX forms are submitted by Drupal in a different way when the submit button is clicked, So you need to just bind the click event to the submit button to detect the form submission, Something like below,

```
jQuery('#submit-form').submit(function() {
  console.log('Form is being submitted');
});
```

Here the restriction is you cant prevent form being submitted, even if you put return false in you custom click handler.